# Why can't refresh JWT token with apollo client

Tags: reactjs, graphql, jwt, apollo-client

So I'm trying to implement a JWT token refresh using `apollo client 3`.
What I ran into is when I execute the following mutation

```
    const REFRESH = gql`
        mutation RefreshToken($token: String!) {
            refreshToken(refreshToken: $token) {
                token
                refreshToken
                success
                errors
            }
        }
    `;
```

apollo changes

```
        const [refreshToken, { loading, error }] = useMutation(REFRESH);
```

to

```
      const [_refreshToken, { loading, error }] = useMutation(REFRESH);
```

and I get an error saying `TypeError: _refreshToken is not a function`.

Is this feature of apollo client premium or something is wrong in my code?